# Pythonic superclass with classmethod constructor: override, inherit, ...?

Tags: python, inheritance, class-method

What is the neatest and most pythonic way to solve this:

Given a class with a `@classmethod` constructor such as in code sample 1. But now subclass it with two classes which both require a totally different additional argument, such as in code sample 2. Should this be solved by using `*args, **kwargs` (sample 3)? Or should I not inherit the `@classmethod` but rather copy it in every class? Or create a superclass `def read_csv` and refer from the subclasses' `@classmethod`?

Subclassing is essential as there are other complex functions in the classes.

Other people working with this code should understand what arguments to pass when initializing the various classes.

**Code sample 1**

```
class Car(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, csv):
       df = pd.read_csv(csv)
       # could be more complex
       return cls(df)

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
```

**Code sample 2**

```
class Ferrari(Car):
    def __init__(self, df, ferrari_logo):
        self.df = df
        self.ferrari_logo = ferrari_logo

    def somethingcomplex(self):
        #complex ferrari method

def Fiat(Car):
    def __init__(self, df, fiat_wheels):
        self.df = df
        self.fiat_wheels = fiat_wheels

    def somethingcomplex(self):
        #complex fiat method

Fiat.from_csv('fiat.csv', fiat_wheels=8)
Ferrari.from_csv('ferrari.csv', ferrari_logo='logo.jpg')
```

**Code sample 3**

```
class Car(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, csv, *args, **kwargs):
       df = pd.read_csv(csv)
       # could be more complex
       return cls(df, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df
```

Comment: "the neatest and most pythonic way " looks like opinion based to me. Also you already have a working solution and it is neat and pythonic enough. If you think there's something wrong in your solution and are looking for ways to improve it you might want to reword the question, at least there would be an actual  problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could avoid defining a new *subclass* (and *subclassing* altogether) each time you have a new attribute for the `Car` class by setting up the attributes of each instance from the `kwargs` passed to the `__init__` method of the class:

```
class Car(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_csv(cls, csv, **kwargs):
        df = pd.read_csv(csv)
        # could be more complex
        return cls(df, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, df=None, **kwargs):
        self.df = df
        for kw in kwargs:
            setattr(self, kw, kwargs[kw])
```

Then you could do:

```
ferrari = Car.from_csv('some.csv', name='ferrari', ferrari_logo='logo.jpg')
fiat = Car.from_csv('fiat.csv', name='fiat', fiat_wheels=8)
```

**Update:**

Then you could subclass the above if you need to define separate methods at the subclass level. You wont need to write a separate `__init__` for each subclass.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Subclassing is required as there are other functions in these classes as well. I made my example a little bit too simple (updated)

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol Oh, then you could subclass this solution. Then you wouldnt need an `__init__` for each subclass. Only the required methods will be defined at the subclass level

Comment: This is a working solution, but does not let my coworkers easily work with my classes, as it is not visible which **kwargs of the subclasses are required / optional and does not show the docs of the __init__ of the subclasses

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol My update was retrofitted to the existing answer. Not clearly stating all the requirements at the start is one thing, editing an answer to meet a new requirement is another :) You may consider asking this with the full requirements in a new question.

Comment: The question is about finding the neatest and most pythonic solution for my subclasses, not leaving out the subclasses. I hope my edit made that clearer. I really appreciate the answer though.

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol But I still don't get it clearly. The sample 3 you posted will not work, as is. The `__init__` should be ready to take the args and `kwargs` you're passing from the class method. Since you suggested the `kwargs` approach, I thought you were up for it. That said, if you're looking to avoid the use `kwargs` due to the reasons you already stated, then sample 2 is your what you want

Comment: code sample 3 passes the args and kwargs to the init of the subclass (if the classmethod is called on the subclass). If the args and kwargs match: this will work. If it does not match: this will throw an error. This is not unwanted behaviour as the arguments HAVE to be passed. But it might be unexpected, as the __init__ doc of the subclass is not visible